# Suggestions of a regression model with time trend

Tags: regression, self-study

I'm thinking about writing my bachelor thesis on how "internet users" (per 100 people) affect gdp per capita for developing countries. I´m thinking of using a regression analysis. But how can I identify the effect of only "internet users" when the gdp has a positive time trend. I will use data from 1995-2015. Helps would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Since this is for your thesis you need to include the self-study tag.

Comment: We're going to need a lot more information before this is answerable. What are your variables? What would it mean for internet users to "affect" GDP vs "no affect" GDP? Etc.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for that. My idea is to examine if the number of "internet users" (per 100 people) as my independent variable affect gdp as a dependent variable. I haven't thought of other possible independent variables that could be of use. But I would like to see if there is a causal relationship between the increasing amount of internet users in developing countries and its gdp. Just looking for ideas. Thanks

Comment: Oh, I will use a OLS regression!

Comment: @MichaelChernick, Just because this is part of a thesis doesn't mean it needs a self-study tag. By that logic, literally any problem encountered in any research project could be called self study.

Comment: @GoF_Logistic The OP has taken my advice so your point is moot and it is consistent with the site rules.

Comment: The idea of a causal relationship is a different point.

Comment: The OP taking your advice is irrelevant. It's a new user who was taking the word of the first commenter. Regardless, it certainly doesn't logically imply my point is moot... Regarding it being consistent with "site rules": the tag wiki description says "A routine question from a textbook, course, or test used for a class or self-study. This community's policy is to "provide helpful hints" for self-study questions." seems entirely off point to this type of question. This question is about research, not routine textbook problems. The fact that this is a student seems totally incidental.